# If set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a basis, there are $n$ vectors in it.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I am trying to prove this. For me the definition of basis was presented without the condition that each vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear combination of the basis vectors. That result was derived later using the result, that a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ includes exactly $n$ vectors. This however isn't clear to me. Here's my attempt to prove it:

I assume, that there are m vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in this linearly independent set:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^m\xi_kx_k=0, \ \ x_k=\left(\begin{matrix}
x_{k1}\\
x_{k2}\\
\vdots\\
x_{kn}
\end{matrix}\right) $$
This can be written as a matrix equation:
$$ \Leftrightarrow\ \underbrace{\left(\begin{matrix}
x_{11}&x_{21}&\dots&x_{m1}\\
x_{12}&x_{22}&\cdots&x_{m2}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
x_{1n}&x_{2n}&\dots&x_{mn}
\end{matrix}\right)}_{=A} \underbrace{\left(\begin{matrix}
\xi_1\\
\xi_2\\
\vdots\\
\xi_m
\end{matrix}\right)}_{=x}=0 $$
Now the question is, when is the solution vector $x$ unique? When this is answered, it should follow that $m = n$.

Comment: You can have a set of $m$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ with $m\leq n$. In particular, we do not have to have $m=n$. For example, $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is a linearly independent set in $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 1):

It's false.  One vector is linearly independent in any $\Bbb R^n$, for $n\gt1$.

Pretty clear that you meant in a *basis*.

For the solution to exist and be unique, in your setup, you need the matrix to be invertible.  In which case it's square, and $m=n$.

Comment: Is there some theorem about this? That I can't find some matrix B for which BAx=x, if A is a non-square matrix?

Comment: Sort of.  A matrix is invertible only when square.

Comment: Doesn't the unique solution only require for the rank of A to be m?

Comment: Yeah but you also need existence.